# Sending email form php (phpmailer) with looping on a mailing list

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using smtp phpmailer to send emails from my website to a mailing list  of 500 to 2 000 emails. So cause on each mail body i have to insert a unique information for each email receiver I'm looping with php on this mailing list to insert this information before sending the mail, and this took time if it's about 1 000 emails or more.

So my question is if there is a better way to do ? and if the use of some paid solution like Sendgrid may fix it ?

Comment: Read the [PHPMailer advice about sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists), and base your code on [the mailing list example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). In my own code, using this kind of approach and a good mail server, I can send 1,000 unique messages in about 4 seconds.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for the documentation . Are you using MTA (postfix) to manage the queue for faster perfomance ?

Comment: Yes. For really high speeds and big volumes, you’ll need to look at commercial solutions. Most open source MTAs are a lot of work to tune.